# Collect Multiple Wikis Via Submodule

Tags: git, github

I have a couple of repositories on GitHub with separate modules that each maintain their manual inside the GitHub wiki.

Now I want to create a repository where the modules are put into the same product. Consequently the wiki of this product should merge the modules' wikis as well.

So since wikis are only Git repositories, I tried adding submodules like this:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/me/my-module.wiki.git
```

That did not work. I cannot access the pages via URL, nor are they added to the TOS automatically.

Since I couldn't find any current info on if subfolders work, I tried that next. Pages in subfolders are displayed in the TOS on the right, and they can be accessed via URL, but the folder is ignored.

So the file *foo/bar.md* is accessed via the URL *bar.md*. Which would be okay for my use case, but evidently submodules are not checked out during the generation of the wiki.

Is there any way to achieve what I want (merging multiple wikis into one)? Else I'll just link to them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is not supported: any subfolder organization within a GitHub wiki would be ignored.

So linking/referencing them through your main wiki page remains the most practical option for now.

Comment: I don't really care for the folder structure. But if there are pages in folders that belong to a submodule, the pages are not displayed at all.

Comment: @SteffiS. Yes, I was referring to folder structure because a submodule is checked out in a folder. Which is not supported. Hence the "pages are not displayed at all"